# Web audio api: smooth transitions between audio fades in/out

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have a 3d space with different zones, each zone has its own sounds. My goal is to have smooth audio transitions when the user moves from one zone to another, basically doing cross-fades between the audio tracks. 
Also I would like to handle gracefully the case when the user changes its mind and abruptly goes back to the zone just left, this means cancel the new audio transitions and revert back to the previous state gradually.

To do this I am using [web audio api](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), in particular [linearRampToValueAtTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/linearRampToValueAtTime) and [cancelScheduledValues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/cancelScheduledValues) to define the fades in/out functions:

```
const fadeIn = (sound, time = 4, gain = 1.0) => {
    sound.gainNode.gain.cancelScheduledValues(sound.context.currentTime)
    !sound.isPlaying && sound.play()
    sound.gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(gain, sound.context.currentTime + time)
}

const fadeOut = (sound, time = 4, gain = 0.0) => {
    sound.gainNode.gain.cancelScheduledValues(sound.context.currentTime)
    sound.gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(gain, sound.context.currentTime + time)
}
```

I am testing this on just one sound, pressing key "I" triggers fadeIn and key "O" triggers fadeOut:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        // I key
        case 73:
            fadeIn(mySound)
            break
        // O key
        case 79:
            fadeOut(mySound)
            break
})
```

I got inconsistent results. Sometimes the audio fades correctly, other times it starts abruptly in the fadeIn or cut in the fadeOut. It seems like calling *cancelScheduledValues* when a transition has not been completed results in an erratic behaviour.  I would like this to work smoothly even when triggering a fadeOut when a fadeIn has not completed yet and viceversa. I have also tried to defer a bit the linearRamps with setTimeout, something like

```
setTimeout(() => sound.gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(gain, sound.context.currentTime + time), 0.1)
```

but got equally wrong results.
Am I using the api incorrectly? Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried the `AudioParam.cancelAndHoldAtTime(time)` method instead `.cancelScheduledValues()`?

Answer (score 2):

I think what's happening here is that, say, you're fading in and you haven't finished the ramp yet.  Then you want a fade out, and cancel the events, including the unfinished fade-in ramp.  Then that fade-in ramp is gone, and the timeline value reverts back to the value of the previous event.

So, as [HankMoody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512831/web-audio-api-smooth-transitions-between-audio-fades-in-out#comment97735354_55512831) suggests, use `cancelAndHoldAtTime` which is meant to handle this problem.  But, AFAIK, only Chrome has this.

To be portable, I think what you want to do is compute where the ramp is at the time you want to cancel.  Let's say the value is `v`.  Then do

```
setValueAtTime(v, context.currentTime);
cancelScheduledValues(context.currentTime + eps);
```

where `eps` is some small value around `1/context.sampleRate` or more.